# finding roots of polynomial in MAGMA or GAP

Tags: polynomials, computer-algebra-systems, gap, magma-cas

Please hint me. I want to find the roots of $x^3+(1-2n)x^2-(1+4n)x+8n^2-10n-1$ with Magma or GAP. In Magma:

> $P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals())$;
>
> $P<n>:= PolynomialRing(Rationals())$;
>
> $f:=x^3+(1-2n)x^2-(1+4n)x+8n^2-10n-1$;
>
> Roots(f);
>
> []

but this polynomial has roots for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Would you be interested in finding them at least for some particular values of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would be able to do better than the generic formulas for roots of a degree polynomial (e.g. Wolfram $\alpha$ will give you these expressions), and these roots are not conveniently represented in the systems you refer to:

The Galois group of the polynomial in $Q(n)[x]$ is $S_3$. So the roots are not cyclotomic, but only lie in a nonabelian extension.